PyMuPdf doesn't recognize every fillable element in a PDF form
I am trying to use Python to read in a PDF form so that I can fill all the elements and then create a new filled in PDF. I found code from this repo and everything works correctly for the most part, but some elements aren't being recognized. Below is what the form looks like when I am editing the elements:

However, when I run my code most but not all of the elements get filled in. In this example I am filling each box with "STRING".

In my code, when I list all of the element names ("other, route_to_1, route_to_2, etc) all the names are correct and have been checked over and over. When I debug my code and look at the variable that stores all the form elements, it's simply misreading some of the elements. I am not sure what is causing this. Whether Acrobat made the form incorrectly, or if there's a problem with the code. Any help is appreciated.
Here's the code I have:
create_pdf.py
from pdf_processing import ProcessPdf

'''
    replace all the constants (the one in caps) with your own lists
'''

'''
    Data Object contains key (keys which are in pdf) and value (actual value) pair
    DATA_OBJECT = {
        'fname': 'Peter', 
        'lname': 'Parker',
        'sex': 'male',
        'mobile': '8888888888'
    }
'''
DATA_OBJECT = {
    "other": "string",
    "route_to_1": "string",
    "route_to_2": "string",
    "route_to_3": "string",
    "route_to_4": "string",
    "route_to_5": "string",
    "route_to_6": "string",
    "route_to_7": "string",
    "route_to_8": "string",
    "route_to_9": "string",
    "route_to_10": "string",
    "route_to_11": "string",
    "route_to_alt_1": "string",
    "route_to_alt_2": "string",
    "route_to_alt_3": "string",
    "route_to_alt_4": "string",
    "route_to_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_aerodrome": "string",
    "dep_elev": "string",
    "dep_atis_id": "string",
    "dep_atis_freq": "string",
    "dest_aerodrome": "string",
    "dest_elev": "string",
    "alt_dest": "string",
    "alt_elev": "string",
    "chan_id_1": "string",
    "chan_freq_1": "string",
    "chan_id_2": "string",
    "chan_freq_2": "string",
    "chan_id_3": "string",
    "chan_freq_3": "string",
    "chan_id_4": "string",
    "chan_freq_4": "string",
    "chan_id_5": "string",
    "chan_freq_5": "string",
    "chan_id_6": "string",
    "chan_freq_6": "string",
    "chan_id_7": "string",
    "chan_freq_7": "string",
    "chan_id_8": "string",
    "chan_freq_8": "string",
    "chan_id_9": "string",
    "chan_freq_9": "string",
    "chan_id_10": "string",
    "chan_freq_10": "string",
    "chan_id_11": "string",
    "chan_freq_11": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_1": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_1": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_2": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_2": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_3": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_3": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_4": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_4": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_5": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_5": "string",
    "course_1": "string",
    "course_2": "string",
    "course_3": "string",
    "course_4": "string",
    "course_5": "string",
    "course_6": "string",
    "course_7": "string",
    "course_8": "string",
    "course_9": "string",
    "course_10": "string",
    "course_11": "string",
    "course_alt_1": "string",
    "course_alt_2": "string",
    "course_alt_3": "string",
    "course_alt_4": "string",
    "course_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_clearance_id": "string",
    "dep_clearance_freq": "string",
    "time_off": "string",
    "dep_app_cont_id": "string",
    "dep_app_cont_freq": "string",
    "dist_1": "string",
    "dist_2": "string",
    "dist_3": "string",
    "dist_4": "string",
    "dist_5": "string",
    "dist_6": "string",
    "dist_7": "string",
    "dist_8": "string",
    "dist_9": "string",
    "dist_10": "string",
    "dist_11": "string",
    "dist_total": "string",
    "alt_route": "string",
    "alt_app_cont_id": "string",
    "alt_app_cont_freq": "string",
    "dist_alt_1": "string",
    "dist_alt_2": "string",
    "dist_alt_3": "string",
    "dist_alt_4": "string",
    "dist_alt_5": "string",
    "ete_1": "string",
    "ete_2": "string",
    "ete_3": "string",
    "ete_4": "string",
    "ete_5": "string",
    "ete_6": "string",
    "ete_7": "string",
    "ete_8": "string",
    "ete_9": "string",
    "ete_10": "string",
    "ete_11": "string",
    "ete_total": "string",
    "ete_alt_1": "string",
    "ete_alt_2": "string",
    "ete_alt_3": "string",
    "ete_alt_4": "string",
    "ete_alt_5": "string",
    "eta_1": "string",
    "ata_1": "string",
    "eta_2": "string",
    "ata_2": "string",
    "eta_3": "string",
    "ata_3": "string",
    "eta_4": "string",
    "ata_4": "string",
    "eta_5": "string",
    "ata_5": "string",
    "eta_6": "string",
    "ata_6": "string",
    "eta_7": "string",
    "ata_7": "string",
    "eta_8": "string",
    "ata_8": "string",
    "eta_9": "string",
    "ata_9": "string",
    "eta_10": "string",
    "ata_10": "string",
    "eta_11": "string",
    "ata_11": "string",
    "eta_total": "string",
    "ata_total": "string",
    "eta_alt_1": "string",
    "ata_alt_1": "string",
    "eta_alt_2": "string",
    "ata_alt_2": "string",
    "eta_alt_3": "string",
    "ata_alt_3": "string",
    "eta_alt_4": "string",
    "ata_alt_4": "string",
    "eta_alt_5": "string",
    "ata_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_gnd_cont_id": "string",
    "dep_gnd_cont_freq": "string",
    "tas": "string",
    "mach": "string",
    "dest_tower_id": "string",
    "dest_tower_freq": "string",
    "leg_fuel_1": "string",
    "leg_fuel_2": "string",
    "leg_fuel_3": "string",
    "leg_fuel_4": "string",
    "leg_fuel_5": "string",
    "leg_fuel_6": "string",
    "leg_fuel_7": "string",
    "leg_fuel_8": "string",
    "leg_fuel_9": "string",
    "leg_fuel_10": "string",
    "leg_fuel_11": "string",
    "leg_fuel_total": "string",
    "alt_altitude": "string",
    "alt_tower_id": "string",
    "alt_tower_freq": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_1": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_2": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_3": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_4": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_5": "string",
    "efr_1": "string",
    "afr_1": "string",
    "efr_2": "string",
    "afr_2": "string",
    "efr_3": "string",
    "afr_3": "string",
    "efr_4": "string",
    "afr_4": "string",
    "efr_5": "string",
    "afr_5": "string",
    "efr_6": "string",
    "afr_6": "string",
    "efr_7": "string",
    "afr_7": "string",
    "efr_8": "string",
    "afr_8": "string",
    "efr_9": "string",
    "afr_9": "string",
    "efr_10": "string",
    "afr_10": "string",
    "efr_11": "string",
    "afr_11": "string",
    "efr_total": "string",
    "afr_total": "string",
    "efr_alt_1": "string",
    "afr_alt_1": "string",
    "efr_alt_2": "string",
    "afr_alt_2": "string",
    "efr_alt_3": "string",
    "afr_alt_3": "string",
    "efr_alt_4": "string",
    "afr_alt_4": "string",
    "efr_alt_5": "string",
    "afr_alt_5": "string",
    "cont_fuel": "string",
    "cont_fuel_1": "string",
    "cont_fuel_2": "string",
    "cont_fuel_3": "string",
    "cont_fuel_4": "string",
    "cont_fuel_5": "string",
    "cont_fuel_6": "string",
    "cont_fuel_7": "string",
    "cont_fuel_8": "string",
    "cont_fuel_9": "string",
    "cont_fuel_10": "string",
    "cont_fuel_11": "string",
    "alt_fuel": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_1": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_2": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_3": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_4": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_tower_id": "string",
    "dep_tower_freq": "string",
    "lbs_ph": "string",
    "lbs_pm": "string",
    "dest_gnd_cont_id": "string",
    "dest_gnd_cont_freq": "string",
    "notes_1": "string",
    "notes_2": "string",
    "notes_3": "string",
    "notes_4": "string",
    "notes_5": "string",
    "notes_6": "string",
    "notes_7": "string",
    "notes_8": "string",
    "notes_9": "string",
    "notes_10": "string",
    "notes_11": "string",
    "notes_12": "string",
    "alt_gnd_cont_id": "string",
    "alt_gnd_cont_freq": "string",
    "notes_alt_1": "string",
    "notes_alt_2": "string",
    "notes_alt_3": "string",
    "notes_alt_4": "string",
    "notes_alt_5": "string",
    "alt_time": "string",
    "route_dest_iaf_fuel": "string",
    "route_alt_iaf_fuel": "string",
    "approaches_fuel": "string",
    "in_air_used_fuel": "string",
    "reserve_fuel": "string",
    "rwy_length_dest": "string",
    "lighting_dest": "string",
    "fuel_dest": "string",
    "ils_dest": "string",
    "loc_dest": "string",
    "asr_dest": "string",
    "par_mins_dest": "string",
    "tac_mins_dest": "string",
    "arr_gear_dest": "string",
    "pubs_dest": "string",
    "notams_dest": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_1": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_2": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_3": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_4": "string",
    "etc_dest": "string",
    "last_cruise_req_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_req_fuel": "string",
    "bingo_req_fuel": "string",
    "last_cruise_appr_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_appr_fuel": "string",
    "rwy_length_alt": "string",
    "lighting_alt": "string",
    "fuel_alt": "string",
    "ils_alt": "string",
    "loc_alt": "string",
    "asr_alt": "string",
    "par_mins_alt": "string",
    "tac_mins_alt": "string",
    "arr_gear_alt": "string",
    "pubs_alt": "string",
    "notams_alt": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_1": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_2": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_3": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_4": "string",
    "etc_alt": "string",
    "last_cruise_res_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_fuel": "string",
    "add_res_fuel": "string",
    "stto_fuel": "string",
    "total_req_fuel": "string",
    "total_aboard_fuel": "string",
    "spare_fuel": "string",
    "last_cruise_total_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_total_fuel": "string",
    "bingo_total": "string",
    "waypoint_1": "string",
    "waypoint_2": "string",
    "waypoint_3": "string",
    "waypoint_4": "string",
    "waypoint_5": "string",
    "waypoint_6": "string",
    "waypoint_7": "string",
    "waypoint_8": "string",
    "waypoint_9": "string",
    "waypoint_10": "string",
    "waypoint_11": "string",
    "waypoint_12": "string",
    "waypoint_13": "string",
    "waypoint_14": "string",
    "waypoint_15": "string",
    "waypoint_16": "string",
    "clearance_cleared_to": "string",
    "clearance_altitude": "string",
    "clearance_freq": "string",
    "clearance_transp": "string",
    "clearance_route": "string"
}

data = DATA_OBJECT

output_file = 'final_pdf.pdf'

temp_files = []

pdf = ProcessPdf('pdf_temp/', output_file)

''' 
    PDF_TEMPLATE_PATH = path/to/your.pdf
'''
data_pdf = pdf.add_data_to_pdf("Blank Jet Log Fillable.pdf", data)

temp_files.append(data_pdf)

pdf_processing.py
import os
import re

import fitz  # requires fitz, PyMuPDF
import pdfrw
import subprocess
import os.path
import sys
from PIL import Image

'''
    replace all the constants (the one in caps) with your own lists
'''

'''
FORM_KEYS is a dictionary (key-value pair) that contains 
1. keys - which are all the key names in the PDF form 
2. values - which are the type for all the keys in the PDF form. (string, checkbox, etc.)

Eg. PDF form contains 
1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Sex (Male or Female)
4. Mobile Number

FORM_KEYS = {
    "fname": "string",
    "lname": "string",
    "sex": "checkbox",
    "mobile": "number"
}

This FORM_KEYS(key) returns the type of value for that key. 
I'm passing this as 2nd argument to encode_pdf_string() function.
'''
FORM_KEYS = {
    "other": "string",
    "route_to_1": "string",
    "route_to_2": "string",
    "route_to_3": "string",
    "route_to_4": "string",
    "route_to_5": "string",
    "route_to_6": "string",
    "route_to_7": "string",
    "route_to_8": "string",
    "route_to_9": "string",
    "route_to_10": "string",
    "route_to_11": "string",
    "route_to_alt_1": "string",
    "route_to_alt_2": "string",
    "route_to_alt_3": "string",
    "route_to_alt_4": "string",
    "route_to_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_aerodrome": "string",
    "dep_elev": "string",
    "dep_atis_id": "string",
    "dep_atis_freq": "string",
    "dest_aerodrome": "string",
    "dest_elev": "string",
    "alt_dest": "string",
    "alt_elev": "string",
    "chan_id_1": "string",
    "chan_freq_1": "string",
    "chan_id_2": "string",
    "chan_freq_2": "string",
    "chan_id_3": "string",
    "chan_freq_3": "string",
    "chan_id_4": "string",
    "chan_freq_4": "string",
    "chan_id_5": "string",
    "chan_freq_5": "string",
    "chan_id_6": "string",
    "chan_freq_6": "string",
    "chan_id_7": "string",
    "chan_freq_7": "string",
    "chan_id_8": "string",
    "chan_freq_8": "string",
    "chan_id_9": "string",
    "chan_freq_9": "string",
    "chan_id_10": "string",
    "chan_freq_10": "string",
    "chan_id_11": "string",
    "chan_freq_11": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_1": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_1": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_2": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_2": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_3": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_3": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_4": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_4": "string",
    "chan_id_alt_5": "string",
    "chan_freq_alt_5": "string",
    "course_1": "string",
    "course_2": "string",
    "course_3": "string",
    "course_4": "string",
    "course_5": "string",
    "course_6": "string",
    "course_7": "string",
    "course_8": "string",
    "course_9": "string",
    "course_10": "string",
    "course_11": "string",
    "course_alt_1": "string",
    "course_alt_2": "string",
    "course_alt_3": "string",
    "course_alt_4": "string",
    "course_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_clearance_id": "string",
    "dep_clearance_freq": "string",
    "time_off": "string",
    "dep_app_cont_id": "string",
    "dep_app_cont_freq": "string",
    "dist_1": "string",
    "dist_2": "string",
    "dist_3": "string",
    "dist_4": "string",
    "dist_5": "string",
    "dist_6": "string",
    "dist_7": "string",
    "dist_8": "string",
    "dist_9": "string",
    "dist_10": "string",
    "dist_11": "string",
    "dist_total": "string",
    "alt_route": "string",
    "alt_app_cont_id": "string",
    "alt_app_cont_freq": "string",
    "dist_alt_1": "string",
    "dist_alt_2": "string",
    "dist_alt_3": "string",
    "dist_alt_4": "string",
    "dist_alt_5": "string",
    "ete_1": "string",
    "ete_2": "string",
    "ete_3": "string",
    "ete_4": "string",
    "ete_5": "string",
    "ete_6": "string",
    "ete_7": "string",
    "ete_8": "string",
    "ete_9": "string",
    "ete_10": "string",
    "ete_11": "string",
    "ete_total": "string",
    "ete_alt_1": "string",
    "ete_alt_2": "string",
    "ete_alt_3": "string",
    "ete_alt_4": "string",
    "ete_alt_5": "string",
    "eta_1": "string",
    "ata_1": "string",
    "eta_2": "string",
    "ata_2": "string",
    "eta_3": "string",
    "ata_3": "string",
    "eta_4": "string",
    "ata_4": "string",
    "eta_5": "string",
    "ata_5": "string",
    "eta_6": "string",
    "ata_6": "string",
    "eta_7": "string",
    "ata_7": "string",
    "eta_8": "string",
    "ata_8": "string",
    "eta_9": "string",
    "ata_9": "string",
    "eta_10": "string",
    "ata_10": "string",
    "eta_11": "string",
    "ata_11": "string",
    "eta_total": "string",
    "ata_total": "string",
    "eta_alt_1": "string",
    "ata_alt_1": "string",
    "eta_alt_2": "string",
    "ata_alt_2": "string",
    "eta_alt_3": "string",
    "ata_alt_3": "string",
    "eta_alt_4": "string",
    "ata_alt_4": "string",
    "eta_alt_5": "string",
    "ata_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_gnd_cont_id": "string",
    "dep_gnd_cont_freq": "string",
    "tas": "string",
    "mach": "string",
    "dest_tower_id": "string",
    "dest_tower_freq": "string",
    "leg_fuel_1": "string",
    "leg_fuel_2": "string",
    "leg_fuel_3": "string",
    "leg_fuel_4": "string",
    "leg_fuel_5": "string",
    "leg_fuel_6": "string",
    "leg_fuel_7": "string",
    "leg_fuel_8": "string",
    "leg_fuel_9": "string",
    "leg_fuel_10": "string",
    "leg_fuel_11": "string",
    "leg_fuel_total": "string",
    "alt_altitude": "string",
    "alt_tower_id": "string",
    "alt_tower_freq": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_1": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_2": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_3": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_4": "string",
    "leg_fuel_alt_5": "string",
    "efr_1": "string",
    "afr_1": "string",
    "efr_2": "string",
    "afr_2": "string",
    "efr_3": "string",
    "afr_3": "string",
    "efr_4": "string",
    "afr_4": "string",
    "efr_5": "string",
    "afr_5": "string",
    "efr_6": "string",
    "afr_6": "string",
    "efr_7": "string",
    "afr_7": "string",
    "efr_8": "string",
    "afr_8": "string",
    "efr_9": "string",
    "afr_9": "string",
    "efr_10": "string",
    "afr_10": "string",
    "efr_11": "string",
    "afr_11": "string",
    "efr_total": "string",
    "afr_total": "string",
    "efr_alt_1": "string",
    "afr_alt_1": "string",
    "efr_alt_2": "string",
    "afr_alt_2": "string",
    "efr_alt_3": "string",
    "afr_alt_3": "string",
    "efr_alt_4": "string",
    "afr_alt_4": "string",
    "efr_alt_5": "string",
    "afr_alt_5": "string",
    "cont_fuel": "string",
    "cont_fuel_1": "string",
    "cont_fuel_2": "string",
    "cont_fuel_3": "string",
    "cont_fuel_4": "string",
    "cont_fuel_5": "string",
    "cont_fuel_6": "string",
    "cont_fuel_7": "string",
    "cont_fuel_8": "string",
    "cont_fuel_9": "string",
    "cont_fuel_10": "string",
    "cont_fuel_11": "string",
    "alt_fuel": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_1": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_2": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_3": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_4": "string",
    "cont_fuel_alt_5": "string",
    "dep_tower_id": "string",
    "dep_tower_freq": "string",
    "lbs_ph": "string",
    "lbs_pm": "string",
    "dest_gnd_cont_id": "string",
    "dest_gnd_cont_freq": "string",
    "notes_1": "string",
    "notes_2": "string",
    "notes_3": "string",
    "notes_4": "string",
    "notes_5": "string",
    "notes_6": "string",
    "notes_7": "string",
    "notes_8": "string",
    "notes_9": "string",
    "notes_10": "string",
    "notes_11": "string",
    "notes_12": "string",
    "alt_gnd_cont_id": "string",
    "alt_gnd_cont_freq": "string",
    "notes_alt_1": "string",
    "notes_alt_2": "string",
    "notes_alt_3": "string",
    "notes_alt_4": "string",
    "notes_alt_5": "string",
    "alt_time": "string",
    "route_dest_iaf_fuel": "string",
    "route_alt_iaf_fuel": "string",
    "approaches_fuel": "string",
    "in_air_used_fuel": "string",
    "reserve_fuel": "string",
    "rwy_length_dest": "string",
    "lighting_dest": "string",
    "fuel_dest": "string",
    "ils_dest": "string",
    "loc_dest": "string",
    "asr_dest": "string",
    "par_mins_dest": "string",
    "tac_mins_dest": "string",
    "arr_gear_dest": "string",
    "pubs_dest": "string",
    "notams_dest": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_1": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_2": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_3": "string",
    "fuel_packet_dest_4": "string",
    "etc_dest": "string",
    "last_cruise_req_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_req_fuel": "string",
    "bingo_req_fuel": "string",
    "last_cruise_appr_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_appr_fuel": "string",
    "rwy_length_alt": "string",
    "lighting_alt": "string",
    "fuel_alt": "string",
    "ils_alt": "string",
    "loc_alt": "string",
    "asr_alt": "string",
    "par_mins_alt": "string",
    "tac_mins_alt": "string",
    "arr_gear_alt": "string",
    "pubs_alt": "string",
    "notams_alt": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_1": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_2": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_3": "string",
    "fuel_packet_alt_4": "string",
    "etc_alt": "string",
    "last_cruise_res_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_fuel": "string",
    "add_res_fuel": "string",
    "stto_fuel": "string",
    "total_req_fuel": "string",
    "total_aboard_fuel": "string",
    "spare_fuel": "string",
    "last_cruise_total_fuel": "string",
    "map_to_iaf_total_fuel": "string",
    "bingo_total": "string",
    "waypoint_1": "string",
    "waypoint_2": "string",
    "waypoint_3": "string",
    "waypoint_4": "string",
    "waypoint_5": "string",
    "waypoint_6": "string",
    "waypoint_7": "string",
    "waypoint_8": "string",
    "waypoint_9": "string",
    "waypoint_10": "string",
    "waypoint_11": "string",
    "waypoint_12": "string",
    "waypoint_13": "string",
    "waypoint_14": "string",
    "waypoint_15": "string",
    "waypoint_16": "string",
    "clearance_cleared_to": "string",
    "clearance_altitude": "string",
    "clearance_freq": "string",
    "clearance_transp": "string",
    "clearance_route": "string"
}


def encode_pdf_string(value, type):
    if type == 'string':
        if value:
            return pdfrw.objects.pdfstring.PdfString.encode(value.upper())
        else:
            return pdfrw.objects.pdfstring.PdfString.encode('')
    elif type == 'checkbox':
        if value == 'True' or value == True:
            return pdfrw.objects.pdfname.BasePdfName('/Yes')
            # return pdfrw.objects.pdfstring.PdfString.encode('Y')
        else:
            return pdfrw.objects.pdfname.BasePdfName('/No')
            # return pdfrw.objects.pdfstring.PdfString.encode('')
    return ''


class ProcessPdf:

    def __init__(self, temp_directory, output_file):
        print('\n##########| Initiating Pdf Creation Process |#########\n')

        print('\nDirectory for storing all temporary files is: ', temp_directory)
        self.temp_directory = temp_directory
        print("Final Pdf name will be: ", output_file)
        self.output_file = output_file

    def add_data_to_pdf(self, template_path, data):
        print('\nAdding data to pdf...')
        template = pdfrw.PdfReader(template_path)

        for page in template.pages:
            annotations = page['/Annots']
            if annotations is None:
                continue

            for annotation in annotations:
                if annotation['/Subtype'] == '/Widget':
                    if annotation['/T']:
                        key = annotation['/T'][1:-1]
                        if re.search(r'.-[0-9]+', key):
                            key = key[:-2]

                        if key in data:
                            annotation.update(
                                pdfrw.PdfDict(V=encode_pdf_string(data[key], FORM_KEYS[key]))
                            )
                        annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(Ff=1))

        template.Root.AcroForm.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(NeedAppearances=pdfrw.PdfObject('true')))
        pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(self.temp_directory + "data.pdf", template)
        print('Pdf saved')

        return self.temp_directory + "data.pdf"

    def convert_image_to_pdf(self, image_path, image_pdf_name):
        print('\nConverting image to pdf...')

        image = Image.open(image_path)
        image_rgb = image.convert('RGB')
        image_rgb.save(self.temp_directory + image_pdf_name)
        return self.temp_directory + image_pdf_name

    def add_image_to_pdf(self, pdf_path, images, positions):
        print('\nAdding images to Pdf...')

        file_handle = fitz.open(pdf_path)
        for position in positions:
            page = file_handle[int(position['page']) - 1]
            if not position['image'] in images:
                continue
            image = images[position['image']]
            page.insertImage(
                fitz.Rect(position['x0'], position['y0'], position['x1'], position['y1']),
                filename=image
            )

        file_handle.save(self.temp_directory + "data_image.pdf")
        print('images added')
        return self.temp_directory + "data_image.pdf"

    def delete_temp_files(self, pdf_list):
        print('\nDeleting Temporary Files...')
        for path in pdf_list:
            try:
                os.remove(path)
            except:
                pass

    def compress_pdf(self, input_file_path, power=3):
        """Function to compress PDF via Ghostscript command line interface"""
        quality = {
            0: '/default',
            1: '/prepress',
            2: '/printer',
            3: '/ebook',
            4: '/screen'
        }

        output_file_path = self.temp_directory + 'compressed.pdf'

        if not os.path.isfile(input_file_path):
            print("\nError: invalid path for input PDF file")
            sys.exit(1)

        if input_file_path.split('.')[-1].lower() != 'pdf':
            print("\nError: input file is not a PDF")
            sys.exit(1)

        print("\nCompressing PDF...")
        initial_size = os.path.getsize(input_file_path)
        subprocess.call(['gs', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4',
                         '-dPDFSETTINGS={}'.format(quality[power]),
                         '-dNOPAUSE', '-dQUIET', '-dBATCH',
                         '-sOutputFile={}'.format(output_file_path),
                         input_file_path]
                        )
        final_size = os.path.getsize(output_file_path)
        ratio = 1 - (final_size / initial_size)
        print("\nCompression by {0:.0%}.".format(ratio))
        print("Final file size is {0:.1f}MB".format(final_size / 1000000))
        return output_file_path


Can you share the PDF in question, both before and after running your code?

Here's a link to a Github repo with all the files. The original PDF is "Jet Log Fillable.pdf" and the output is in "pdf_temp/data.pdf"

I'm dumb. Never linked the repo: https://github.com/jpwolfe9912/Jet-Log-Filler
